# Azure: Docker container on VM timing out on public address randomly after creation?

Tags: azure, docker

Bit of a weird one this.

Basically I'm setting up a HAProxy docker container on a VM (Ubuntu) in Azure. The VM has a public address and the container is configured to listen on port 80 like normal.

It works some of the time. When it does everything is grand and the container works as expected.

However when I run my automation, which deletes and recreates the docker container by default to pick up the latest image, it always passes but the container times out when I try to load up the public address. This seems to happen around half of the time.

Nothing else has changed in this scenario. Firewall is correct, the port itself is open but it just times out. Restarting the docker container solves the issue most of the time.

This doesn't happen when I try the same thing on GCP so I assume it's something more Azure related. Any help would be awesome thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears this was due to needing `net.ipv4.ip_unprivileged_port_start` configured with the HAProxy container.

Since adding that I've not seen the issue. Apologies for the noise!